# Dictionary intersection based on keys, TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Index

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with some different youtube datasets and I wanted to see which tags persisted over time and the amount of videos with them, I'm using pandas so I can plot the data easily.

I've made a solution but I don't get why it works, or rather, why something I think is the same thing doesn't work.

Simplified form:

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['a',
    'a',
    'a',
    'b',
    'b',
    'c'],
    ['a',
    'a',
    'b',
    'b',
    'b',
    'd']
]

res = []

for tags in data:
    cnt = Counter()
    for tag in tags:
        cnt[tag] += 1

    series = pd.Series()
    for tag in cnt.most_common():
        series[tag[0]] = tag[1]

    res.append(series)

temp = res[0].keys()
for each in res[1:]:
    temp &= each.keys()

try:
    for i in range(len(res)):
        res[i] = res[temp]
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)

i = 0
for each in res:
    res[i] = each[temp]
    i += 1

print(res)
```

The dummy data is simple, a and b are the tags that intersect but I don't understand why for each works but for i in range doesn't when it's all the same types except I thought I could save 2 lines with i in range

output:

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not Index
[a    3
b    2
dtype: int64, a    2
b    3
dtype: int64]
```

Answer (score 0):

10 seconds in posting this I realized what I did wrong and quickly wanted to delete this but saw this already has views and panicked as someone is seeing this shameful question....

Oh well, in my defense my brain was fried... edited the title so maybe my code will be found by someone and help them

I wasn't actually accessing the pandas series but the list itself....

```
res[i] = res[temp]
```

into

```
res[i] = res[i][temp]
```

and it works...